# Animation not working when view presented with an UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I try to make an animation with an image in my view but it doesn't work: my image is at the final position without animation.

```
UIImage *myImg = [UIImage imageNamed : @"Img72.png"];
UIImageView *myImgView =[ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: myImg ];
myImgView.frame= CGRectMake(250,50,72,72);
[self.view addSubview:myImgView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay: 0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:100.0];
                     [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
                     myImgView.frame= CGRectMake(50,250,72,72);
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
[myImgView release];
```

The same animation code work perfectly in another view. I finally find that it's come from the way I display the view with this code:

```
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal; //KO
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

The problem is the `modalTransitionStyle`. When I comment the line (with //KO) it finally works. I test the other transition style and all the other works (`UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical`, `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve`, `UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl`)

I made an `viewDidLoadProject` (Utility App) and just add the animation code in the two view in `viewDidLoad` method.

Where is the problem? Is it an Apple bug? How can I have a flip transition AND my animation working in the second view?

Here is my example project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9204589/testFlipAnimation.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems more natural to start to play with the interface when all the system stuff is done, `didAppear` must be used for that purpose i believe (yes, it works :))

`FlipsideViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImage *myImg = [UIImage imageNamed : @"Img72.png"];
    UIImageView *myImgView =[ [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: myImg ];
    myImgView.frame= CGRectMake(250,50,72,72);
    [self.view addSubview:myImgView];


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay: 0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:100.0];
                         [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
                         myImgView.frame= CGRectMake(50,250,72,72);
                     }
                     completion:NULL];
    [myImgView release];


    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: YEEEEESSSSSS, thanks for your quick and perfect answer :-) It was so simple. "J'avais la tête dans le guidon" as we say in France.

Comment: BULLS eye! just what i wanted